# Logging received messages in Akka

Tags: java, akka

I am using Akka actors from within Java and am trying to turn on the logging of messages. Based on the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/logging.html), it seems that setting `akka.actor.debug.receive` should cause all messages to be logged.  The following test should log the `"hello"` message being sent and received.

```
import akka.actor.AbstractLoggingActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.japi.pf.ReceiveBuilder;
import akka.pattern.Patterns;
import akka.testkit.JavaTestKit;
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
import io.scalac.amqp.Persistent$;
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration$;

public class LoggingTest
{
    @Before
    public void createActorSystem() {
        Config config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
                "akka: {" +
                "  actor: { debug: { receive: on, fsm: on, unhandled: on, autoreceive: on }}," +
                "  log-config-on-start: off" +
                "  ,loglevel: DEBUG" +
                "  ,stdout-loglevel: DEBUG" +
                "}");
        system = ActorSystem.create(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                                    config);

    }

    @After
    public void shutdownActorSystem() {
        JavaTestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system);
    }

    private static class TestActorWithLogging extends AbstractLoggingActor {
        public TestActorWithLogging(ActorRef target) {
            receive(ReceiveBuilder.
                    matchAny(msg -> target.tell(msg, self())).
                    build());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void messageLogging() {
        new JavaTestKit(system) {{
            system.log().debug("Running messageLogging");

            ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(Props.create(TestActorWithLogging.class, getRef()));
            send(actor, "hello");
            expectMsgEquals("hello");
        }};
    }


    private ActorSystem system;
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following output.  Lifecycle messages are logged, so the config is being applied.  However, I don't see any log statements about the `"hello"` message.

```
Running LoggingTest
[DEBUG] [09/17/2015 16:49:48.893] [main] [EventStream] StandardOutLogger started
[DEBUG] [09/17/2015 16:49:49.020] [main] [EventStream(akka://LoggingTest)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [09/17/2015 16:49:49.020] [main] [EventStream(akka://LoggingTest)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [09/17/2015 16:49:49.023] [main] [EventStream(akka://LoggingTest)] Default Loggers started
[DEBUG] [09/17/2015 16:49:49.023] [main] [EventStream(akka://LoggingTest)] Default Loggers started
[DEBUG] [09/17/2015 16:49:49.050] [main] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(LoggingTest)] Running messageLogging
[DEBUG] [09/17/2015 16:49:49.103] [LoggingTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://LoggingTest/system] received AutoReceiveMessage Envelope(Terminated(Actor[akka://LoggingTest/user]),Actor[akka://LoggingTest/user])
[DEBUG] [09/17/2015 16:49:49.104] [LoggingTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [EventStream] shutting down: StandardOutLogger started
[DEBUG] [09/17/2015 16:49:49.104] [LoggingTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [EventStream] shutting down: StandardOutLogger started
[DEBUG] [09/17/2015 16:49:49.106] [LoggingTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [EventStream] all default loggers stopped
[DEBUG] [09/17/2015 16:49:49.111] [LoggingTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://LoggingTest/] received AutoReceiveMessage Envelope(Terminated(Actor[akka://LoggingTest/system]),Actor[akka://LoggingTest/system])
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.33 sec
```

What should I be doing to log the messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting you mention, `akka.actor.debug.receive` is only for the Scala API for actors.  This is because of the nature of how the `receive` `PartialFunction` is invoked in Scala.  In Scala, the actor framework first sees if there is a `case` defined for the input message using `isDefinedAt`.  If there is a `case` defined for the message, then it will call `apply` on the `PartialFunction` and the message is handled.  But if the message is not handled, then `apply` is not called.  In order to log all messages, handled or otherwise, the Scala framework needed a facility to wrap around the `PartialFunction` evaluation to log regardless, and that facility is this setting plus the `LoggingReceive` utility that wraps the `receive` `PartialFunction` and uses that setting to control logging.

In the Java world, you don't have this "check then apply" semantic.  All messages hit the `onReceive` method and in there, your `instanceof` handling will determine if the message is handled or not.  Because of this, it's pretty easy to define an abstract base Java class that implements `onReceive` and logs accordingly (possibly based on that same setting) before delegating to a subclass method for actual message evaluation and handling.

Comment: It looks like the messages go through `aroundReceive`, not `onReceive`.  But other than that, this works.